# Getstream data import pattern

Tags: getstream-io

We are preparing import data to submit to getstream. The pattern in your [documentation](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#import) looks like:

```
// start by adding multiple activities, grouped by feedId
{"instruction": "add_activities", "feedId": "user:1", "data": [{"actor": 1, "verb": "tweet", "object": 1, "foreign_id": "tweet:1", "time": "2016-04-20T17:47:40.529165"},{"actor": 2, "verb": "tweet", "object": 2, "foreign_id": "tweet:2", "time": "2016-04-20T17:47:40.529165"}]}
// follow instructions, grouped by feedId, timeline:1 follows user:2 and user:3
{"instruction": "follow", "feedId": "timeline:1", "data": ["user:2", "user:3"]}
// instructions are separated by newlines, timeline:2 follows user:3 and user:4
{"instruction": "follow", "feedId": "timeline:2", "data": ["user:3", "user:4"]}
```

I have 2 questions regarding the format:

1 - How can I define number of feeds to copy while following? Referring to [activity_copy_limit](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#following)

2 - How many activities I can put in one instruction of `add_activities`? Is it unlimited, or I will have to break it into the 100, 100 chunks?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `activity_copy_limit` option isn't available during imports.
2. No limit on activities included in the `add_activities` statements.